# Can't select any options when reviewing a post I flagged

Tags: bug

I have access to the Low Quality Posts queue.  I flagged a post and it appeared in the queue, but I couldn't select any options as shown below.

[image: Low quality posts queue]

This is sensible, otherwise people could flag/vote and abuse the system.  However it seems that things probably shouldn't appear in the queue if I flagged them.  All I could do was say "Looks OK" or "Skip", which is pointless because the post should definitely have been closed.

Is the fact it appears in the queue (pointlessly) a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Read the little note in the bottom right corner: *"You flagged this question for closure 4 hours ago"*.  You have already voted on this question, so it won't let you vote again.

It seems more clever software would not have shown you this entry in the review queue because you can't do anything with it, but it is what it is.

Comment: Yes - I understand why I can't vote.  My question is whether it appearing in the queue is a bug.  It's not like Stack Exchange isn't clever software.

Comment: @David -- If that is your question, it would be a little clearer if you could edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Done @ScottSeidman, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193128/low-quality-posts-you-have-already-flagged) which seems to have very low priority in the eyes of SO devs. I suggest you upvote and bump the request to fix it.